# jQuery simple fade functions not running smooth in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fade

I've got a correctly working [website](http://www.3xloutdoormedia.nl/), which runs very smooth in FF and Chrome, but IE shows the fadeIn and fadeOut not fluently, but it flickers...
Is there a solution for this?
I have a bgstretcher on the background, maybe this is making it too heavy for IE?
Thanks in advance,
Wouter

Comment: As far as I remember is there no opacity-support in IE... Therefore it just show()s the blocks without fading... Due to the animation the flickering happens...

Comment: [http://www.google.com/search?q=reasons+to+use+Internet+Explorer](http://www.google.com/search?q=reasons+to+use+Internet+Explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE Doesnt support opacity. thats a common problem, its uses filters. there is no way to run this smoothly in IE.

or in its real name. Internet **Exploader**.

Comment: sorry, i meant that some animations, for instance also the slideDown one, are not going smoothly. The fadeIn was just an example. I knew that IE doesn't support opacity, but I thought I had that one covered using a transparant .png file. Apparantly this is helping a bit, but not as nice as in FF and Chrome/Safari. Thanks for your advice anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, lets wait for IE 9 and pray

Comment: i'm lucky, enlisting for 3 years to the army. when I'm back.. i'm going back to a world that has IE9!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a kludge, but it gets around the problem:

```
if (jQuery.support.opacity) {
    x.fadeIn(100);
}
else {
    x.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. I can't test it now though, working on a different project. Is the .show() animation better for IE than the .fadeIn() animation? Bye, Wouter

Comment: show() is not an animation. It just changes the display from none to block. With this code, browsers without opacity will fade in and others will just pop in. Since IE9 will be better behaved, I'm now spending no time on <IE9 work-arounds.